# How to allow client computers connecting with ospf to a server to access a link that is coming from an external server through vpn

Tags: linux, server, openvpn, ipsec

I am running a server that is getting a link from an external organization which is connected via p to p vpn. i want my client computers to access the link and my client computers are connected to my server via `ospf`. I need a solution that allows traffic coming from my client computers to point to the link coming from the external server.

I used point to point VPN and I cannot connect to the remote server because i have many client computers that are resulting in IP conflicts at th main server from the external organization

Comment: managed to solve it. I used reverse proxy and its working fine.

Comment: if anyone needs the same solution please do not hesitate to ask